# Prospective employers promising that I can pick up product/tech responsibilities from marketing/growth role over time. How to verify?

Tags: interviewing

I've had a number of calls with prospective employers who, after I explain with them I want to transition to a product/tech-oriented role after some time with them, promise that I can make the transition. I understand this is probably just talk, but if an employer is serious, what are examples of evidence here?

Comment: If they 'promise' it, get it in writing with a defined timescale. Otherwise, it doesn't exist and will never happen.

Comment: Ask to speak to your future team members. They'll be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**People who have done it before.**

Check to see if anyone else has made that transition, either on LinkedIn or just ask to be put in touch with some examples.

Do they have anyone who went from marketing to tech/product on their current team? That would be the most concrete evidence.

Answer (score 1):

> How to verify?

You cannot verify that something will happen in the future. It is (still) a physical non-sense.

What can you do? You **make sure** it will happen in the future. Or, at least, you make sure to maximize the chance of it happening in the future.

For that, there is a very simple tool. It is called **contract**. In the contact it must be specified something like this:

> Initially, OP will work XYZ. Between dates K and L, OP will transition to role EFG. OP will fully occupy role EFG starting with date M. The transitioning plan follows: (bla blah bleah).

If it is not written in the contract, the company will be free to do anything they want, and you will have no way to enforce that.

Even more, you might add tot eh contract a clause (if the company is professional and with good intentions) that they will pay some "penalties" if the said transition does not end properly, because of reasons you cannot control.